# Constructing commutative diagram up to homotopy from a smooth map.

Tags: differential-topology, characteristic-classes, simplicial-complex

This is from the proof of Theorem 20.7 in "Characteristic classes" by Milnor and Stasheff. 
Let $f : M^n \rightarrow S^r$ be a smooth map where $M$ is smooth $n$-dimensional manifold and $S^r$ is $r$-dimensional sphere and $n-r = 4i$.
The book gives me the diagram commutative up to homotopy.

[image]

This is a diagram commutative up to homotopy, where $g$ is piecewise linear and $t, s$ are smooth triangulations and $K$ and $L$ are simplicial complexes.
How can we construct the diagram?

Comment: Can you not just take $g$ to be a piecewise linear homotopy of $s^{-1}\circ f \circ t$?

Comment: A map $f : K \rightarrow L$ between simplicial complexes is called piecewise linear if there exists a subdivision $s : K \rightarrow K^{'}$ so that the composition $f \circ s$ is simplexwise linear. 
Is $s^{-1} \circ f \circ t$ homotopic to a piecewise linear map??

Comment: Yes, this is the simplicial approximation theorem.

Comment: That's right. Thank you!